# PHP MySQL Print Cursor to web page?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written a stored procedure. I am not getting the data that I am looking for and I am wondering how I can see the output line by line. My experience is heavy in PLSQL so I would normally just write to a webpage and see the results. Is there any way that I can take the stored procedure below and print it out to html using php or use PHPMyAdmin to see where the error is. I am sure it is something simple I am missing in the procedure but after 3 hours I do not know. I am flying blind trying to teach myself PHP and MySQL.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_szAwayTeam varchar(5);
DECLARE v_szHomeTeam varchar(5);
DECLARE v_nPointsAway INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_nPointsHome INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_nPointsFor INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_nPointsAgainst INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE curSchedule CURSOR
FOR
SELECT szAway, szHome, nPointsAway, nPointsHome FROM schedule_master WHERE 
szGame = 'R' ORDER BY dtGame, dtTime;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

OPEN curSchedule;
    get_Sched: LOOP

    FETCH curSchedule INTO v_szAwayTeam, v_szHomeTeam, v_nPointsAway, 
    v_nPointsHome;

        IF (v_nPointsAway < v_nPointsHome) THEN
            SELECT nPointsFor INTO v_nPointsFor FROM standings_master WHERE 
            idTeam = v_szHomeTeam;
            SET v_nPointsFor = (v_nPointsHome + v_nPointsFor);
            UPDATE standings_master SET nPointsFor = v_nPointsFor WHERE 
            idTeam = v_szHomeTeam;


            SELECT nPointsAgainst INTO v_nPointsAgainst FROM 
            standings_master WHERE idTeam = v_szAwayTeam;
            SET v_nPointsAgainst = (v_nPointsAway + v_nPointsAgainst);
            UPDATE standings_master SET nPointsAgainst = v_nPointsAgainst 
            WHERE idTeam = v_szAwayTeam;

            COMMIT;


        ELSEIF (v_nPointsHome < v_nPointsAway) THEN


            SELECT nPointsFor INTO v_nPointsFor FROM standings_master WHERE 
            idTeam = v_szAwayTeam;
            SET v_nPointsFor = (v_nPointsAway + v_nPointsFor);
            UPDATE standings_master SET nPointsFor = v_nPointsFor WHERE 
            idTeam = v_szAwayTeam;

            SELECT nPointsAgainst INTO v_nPointsAgainst FROM 
            standings_master WHERE idTeam = v_szHomeTeam;
            SET v_nPointsAgainst = (v_nPointsHome + v_nPointsAgainst);
            UPDATE standings_master SET nPointsAgainst = v_nPointsAgainst 
            WHERE idTeam = v_szHomeTeam;

            COMMIT;             
        END IF;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_Sched;
        END IF;     

        END LOOP get_Sched;

CLOSE curSchedule;

END
```

Comment: i think you can declare temp table , insert data into it with cursor at last return the temp table as a result at the end of your proc

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a stored procedure for this at all in MySQL.

I understand you come from the world of Oracle PL/SQL, which provides a rich development environment for web apps based on stored procedures.

MySQL stored procedures are crap compared to Oracle's robust web development environment.

- MySQL stored procs have no packages.
- There is no procedure debugger.
- There is no support for web page output.
- There's no standard libraries of procedures.
- There's no compiling procedures. They are compiled on demand *every time you use them*.

Most MySQL developers are more productive coding their apps using complementary scripting languages, instead of developing using database packages and procedures. PHP is one popular scripting language, but there are others too.

I think the logic of your stored procedure example can be boiled down to two simpler UPDATE statements. You don't need to use cursors.

Below is an example (though I haven't tested it) showing use of PHP with its database API, called PDO. Do yourself a favor since you're learning PHP in 2017: *skip the outdated mysql and mysqli APIs.*

There's a very nice tutorial for PDO here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

There's a very nice site for general PHP best practices here: http://www.phptherightway.com

```
<?php

// You need to set your DSN and $user and $password.
// I recommend putting them in a config file, and read it with
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
// Remember to put the config file *outside* your HTTP
// document root, to avoid the risk of any client reading it!

$config = parse_ini_file('/path/to/config.ini');

try {
    $db = new PDO($config['dsn'], $config['user'], $config['password']);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    die('Sorry, the database failed. Please contact the webmaster.');
}

$sql = "
    UPDATE standings_master AS m
    JOIN schedule_master AS s ON m.idTeam = s.szHome
    SET m.nPointsFor = m.nPointsFor + IF(s.nPointsAway < s.nPointsHome, s.nPointsHome, 0),
        m.nPointsAgainst = m.nPointsAgainst + IF(s.nPointsAway > s.nPointsHome, s.nPointsAway, 0)
    WHERE s.szGame = 'R'";

$db->exec($sql);

$sql = "
    UPDATE schedule_master AS s
    JOIN standings_master AS m ON m.idTeam = s.szAway
    SET m.nPointsFor = m.nPointsFor + IF(s.nPointsAway > s.nPointsHome, s.nPointsAway, 0),
        m.nPointsAgainst = m.nPointsAgainst + IF(s.nPointsAway < s.nPointsHome, s.nPointsHome, 0)
    WHERE s.szGame = 'R'";

$db->exec($sql);
```

Then to display the result, you need to use a query with a result set, like `SELECT`:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT idTeam, PointsFor, PointsAgainst
    FROM standings_master
    ORDER BY PointsFor DESC";

$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Points For</th>
  <th>Points Against</th>
 </tr>

<?php
foreach ($results AS $row) {
?>

 <tr>
  <td><?= $row['idTeam'] ?></td>
  <td><?= $row['PointsFor'] ?></td>
  <td><?= $row['PointsAgainst'] ?></td>
 </tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
```